# number of submodules of direct sum of simple modules

Tags: modules, direct-sum

Let $M$ be a simple $R$ module. show that the number of submodules of $M \oplus M$ can be infinite.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit](http://goo.gl/mLWc8) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It's always better to add your thoughts and show your efforts with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $M=R=\mathbb{R}$. This is a simple $\mathbb{R}$-module, obviously. Note that for each $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ the set
$$M_\lambda:=\{(x,\lambda x): x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$$
is a submodule of $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$.